# Making class library project visible to another .net project

Tags: .net-core, .net-assembly, class-library

Hello i have a solution with an `.net-core` app and a `class library`.How can i make the class library's classes visible to the `.net-core` app without declaring all of them `public` ?
Should i just use the `InternalsVisibleTo` ?

Comment: What's the problem with using public? This is kind of the whole point. Your library public "interface" (aka public API) should be `public`.

Comment: Then why cannot you use InternalsVisibleTo?

Comment: I thought there are other ways to maintain classes within an assembly with various access levels and still make them visible to other assemblies.

Comment: I think you might be able to achieve something on those lines. I vaguely remember reading something about a way to add visibility of files from an assembly into another file.
Having said that, I really really suggest you ask yourself why you would want to do this. What advantage would you get? Marking things as `public` has exactly this purpose...especially if you are the one who is writing the class.